# How to set Vector3 direction via an enum?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Summary:**
I want to set the direction of a vector3 in a script. The script is for a conveyor belt. I want to be able to select which way the conveyor belt goes.

**Issue:**
I can't seem to figure out how to set the vector3 from an enum.
Below is the line which contains the vector3 I'd like to change with the enum.
'''

```
rBody.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```

Here's the enum.

```
public enum direction {up, down, left, right, forward, backward};
public direction moveDirection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `switch - case`

```
Vector3 dir;
switch(moveDirection)
{
    case direction.up:
        dir = Vector3.up;
        break;

    case direction.down:
        dir = Vector3.down;
        break;

    case direction.right:
        dir = Vector3.right;
        break;

    case direction.left:
        dir = Vector3.left;
        break;

    case direction.forward:
        dir = Vector3.forward;
        break;

    case direction.back:
        dir = Vector3.back;
        break;

    default:
        throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException();
}

rBody.position += dir * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```

---

Or make it a dictionary right away

```
private Dictionary<direction, Vector3> directionToVector = new Dictionary<direction, Vector3>
{
    {direction.up, Vector3.up},
    {direction.down, Vector3.down},
    {direction.right, Vector3.right},
    {direction.left, Vector3.left},
    {direction.forward, Vector3.forward},
    {direction.back, Vector3.back}
}
```

and then simply use it like

```
var dir = directionToVector [moveDirection];
rBody.position += dir * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```